# SSL failed handshake in Kafka Broker after upgrade

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Im doing upgrade from CP5.0.0 to CP5.5.1 where I use GSSAPI as security.protocol and where I have 2 listeners: SASL_PLAINTEXT and SSL

Here is part of important configuration:

```
# SASL Additions
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=GSSAPI
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=GSSAPI
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
zookeeper.sasl.enabled=true
#confluent.metrics.reporter.sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI


# SSL Additions
ssl.truststore.location=/app/certs/kafka.truststore.jks
#ssl.truststore.password=<redacted>
ssl.truststore.password==<redacted>
ssl.keystore.location=/app/certs/broker11.jks
ssl.keystore.password==<redacted>
ssl.key.password==<redacted>
ssl.client.auth=required

# Extra
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://broker1.uat.tel.be:9092,SSL://broker1.uat.tel.be:9093
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://broker1.uat.tel.be:9092,SSL://broker1.uat.tel.be:9093
```

While doing upgrade I noticed this INFO message which repeats itself every 10seconds (10.12.24.41 is broker21 and 10.12.24.40 is broker11) **IPs are dummy ones dont worry**:

```
[2021-09-09 14:31:03,979] DEBUG [SslTransportLayer channelId=10.12.24.40:9093-10.12.24.40:35714-139 key=sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@56ac9d24] SSL handshake completed successfully with peerHost '10.12.24.40' peerPort 35714 peerPrincipal 'CN=node1.example.com' cipherSuite 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256' (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
[2021-09-09 14:31:03,979] DEBUG [SocketServer brokerId=11] Successfully authenticated with /10.12.24.40 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2021-09-09 14:31:03,983] DEBUG [SslTransportLayer channelId=10.12.24.40:9093-10.12.24.41:37660-140 key=sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@255f77ab] SSLEngine.closeInBound() raised an exception. (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
[2021-09-09 14:31:03,983] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=11] Failed authentication with /10.12.24.41 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

One thing to tell is that my node certificate is starting with CN=broker1.uat.tel.be, the same advertiser.listener for both protocol is setup but hostname of host is

```
$ hostname -f 
bigd1111.ces.teb.be
```

In */etc/hosts* I have both hostnames configured just in case.

Now, prior the upgrade on CP5.0.0 I couldnt see issue:

```
[2021-09-09 14:31:03,983] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=11] Failed authentication with /10.12.24.41 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

but after upgrade to CP5.5.1 issue is starting to appear. I’m not sure what is exactly happening but going through release notes I see that some changes has been done in CP5.0.0 where `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=` has been set to **https** by default.

The thing is that does not impact me/or shouldnt as I already had the same property set as Im already using CP5.0.0.
I have tried to make client connections and post messages to SSL listener and that worked without any issues, but still, INFO message about failed handshake is little bit worrying me.

*INFO message even pops when I place ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=  to none
TL;DR* but I **do not want to do that**

I thought, maybe there is a problem with my server certificates and chains, so I run:

```
 openssl s_client -connect broker1.uat.tel.be:9093
```

and that gave me this output:

```
    CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R3, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign RSA OV SSL CA 2018
verify return:1
depth=0 C = <redacted>, ST = <redacted>, L = <redacted>, O = <redacted>, CN = broker1.uat.tel.be
verify return:1
140151863281552:error:1408E0F4:SSL routines:ssl3_get_message:unexpected message:s3_both.c:408:
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/C=<redacted>/<redacted>=<redacted>/L=<redacted>/O=<redacted>/CN=broker1.uat.tel.be
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign RSA OV SSL CA 2018
1 s:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign RSA OV SSL CA 2018
   i:/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
2 s:/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
   i:/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<redacted because post letter limit>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=<redacted>/ST=<redacted>/L=<redacted>/O=<redacted>/CN=broker1.uat.tel.be
issuer=/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign RSA OV SSL CA 2018
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign RSA OV SSL CA 2018
/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
Client Certificate Types: ECDSA sign, RSA sign, DSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:0x04+0x08:0x05+0x08:0x06+0x08:0x09+0x08:0x0A+0x08:0x0B+0x08:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 9964 bytes and written 169 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: E6D28B4F099C01BB9202BDE567C2352AC13721C3658B5DE07CC508D47EA7748E
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: B27DE2F9E4F724DC6653A8AC1B86D452DE0770CB49172C66AEA147E9CFEEECDC25D033F35337F24EC21F7C947312EBF7
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1631264045
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Even, when I got 0 in broker I could see INFO message saying that handshake failed from the IP I run openssl command, which is again, weird.

If someone can help I would be really grateful as Im debugging this for days already and dont know where even to look anymore. TIP: all clients are okay, I can establish connection with Producer/Consumer certificate and write/read data without them complaining.

***UPDATE:***

After enabling ssl debug in broker I was able to get following output, if that helps:

```
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|75|data-plane-kafka-network-thread-11-ListenerName(SSL)-SSL-13|2021-09-10 14:33:01.313 CEST|TransportContext.java:313|Fatal (BAD_CERTIFICATE): Empty server certificate chain (
"throwable" : {
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Empty server certificate chain
```

If I wait for failed handshake between Kafka brokers then message is like this:

```
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|76|data-plane-kafka-network-thread-11-ListenerName(SSL)-SSL-15|2021-09-10 14:55:13.686 CEST|TransportContext.java:313|Fatal (BAD_CERTIFICATE): Received fatal alert: bad_certificate (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:279)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:672)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:627)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:443)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:422)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:634)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:504)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:363)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:286)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:173)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:547)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485)
        at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:893)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:792)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)}
```

Comment: You need a mutual TLS, because `ssl.client.auth=required`, so test it with `openssl s_client` and with `-cert`, `-key` parameters.